# Regular Expression in php email checker continue

Tags: php

I have this:

```
$pattern = "/[0-9]/";
if (preg_match($pattern, $email) = 1) {
    continue;
}
```

wondering why it doesn't work and how can I fix it?

Comment: You are assigning the 'variable'/function(?) instead of checking it. Try `==` instead

Comment: Thankyou, however even the continue function sis flagging up?

Comment: Can you please explain what you try to do? I don't quite understand your code without any context.

Comment: What should this code do?

Comment: I am trying to check an email address for any integers. If there is any intergers, I would like to continue running the rest of the code

Comment: `continue` can only be used in a loop or switch. Is this `if` statement inside one?

Comment: no. Is there a work around, I just need it to continue running the code thats all

Comment: If you want a piece of code to run only if the condition matches, then that code should go between the `{` and `}` characters.

Comment: Or you can exit\die\return if condition is __not true__.

Comment: okay perfect, thanks so much. I shall reply to this if I come across any other issues. :)

Comment: @DawudLatif When you say you are checking the email address, does that mean numbers have to be before @ symbol, or can be after @ symbol, because your code would trigger on `name@abc123.com`.

Comment: Numbers have to be before the @, and everything after the @ has to be gmail.com, however I have zero clue

Comment: You can also use `filter_var` so you don't have to write your own regex: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp

Comment: thanks much appreciated, life savers

Comment: This should'nt be part of the comment section. When you don't know how to use PHPMyAdmin or MySQL you are welcome to ask another question or search the internet. For example I always use W3Schools https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp